# Can "static const char array" include a member of variable on C language

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

My Code is following

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *a ="this is a";
static const char *b ="this is b";

char *comb_ab[2] =
{
    a,
    b
};

int main() {

    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<sizeof(comb_ab)/sizeof(comb_ab[0]); i++) {
        printf("%s\n",comb_ab[i]);
    }
}
```

this code is working on G++ compiler(C++) normally. but GCC is not working..
the output is following

```
test.c:8:2: error: initializer element is not constant
  a,
  ^
test.c:8:2: error: (near initialization for ‘comb_ab[0]’)
test.c:10:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 };
 ^
test.c:10:1: error: (near initialization for ‘comb_ab[1]’)
```

how to include memeber of variable in the static const *char array on gcc? 
please help me!

Comment: You try to initialize `char *` with `const char *`, this is a type mismatch. Check your g++ compiler output

Comment: Note that `const char *a` is a non-constant pointer to a constant array of `char`, if you want a constant pointer you need `char const * const a`.

Comment: Tested on `g++.exe (tdm-1) 5.1.0`, the code won't compile, which is expected, because `static const char *` means 'pointer to **constant char** with internal linkage and static duration lifetime', yet you're initializing it into an 'array of pointer of **non-const** char'.

Answer (score 6):

In C, initializers for objects of static storage duration must be *constant expressions*.

The value of a variable is never a constant expression, even if it is a `const`-qualified variable.

So you cannot use the value of `a` as initializer for `comb_ab`.

In C++ initializers may have runtime evaluation.

To fix the C version you could make `comb_ab` be non-static and defined inside `main`; or you could have code inside `main` which "initializes" the global `comb_ab` with the right values.

---

Also you have a type mismatch: you try to use `const char *` to initialize `char *`. But even if you fix that, the previous problem remains. Using g++ you should have got a compiler diagnostic about that.

Answer (score 3):

You might use an address of object with static storage duration as constant expression at the cost of another level of indirection. This is formally known in C as *address constant* (C11, §6.6/9).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *a = "this is a";
static const char *b = "this is b";

static const char **comb_ab[2] =
{
    &a,
    &b
};

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(comb_ab)/sizeof(comb_ab[0]); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *comb_ab[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course, it would be simpler to merge `a` and `b` literals with the array. Consider following design:

```
static const char *comb_ab[] =
{
    "this is a",
    "this is b",
};
```

Comment: Another option is to make `a` and `b` arrays of `const char`: `static const char a[] = "this is a"; static const char b[] = "this is b"; static const char *comb_ab[2] = { a, b };`.